# psql change timestamp type with timezone

Tags: python, postgresql, psql, alembic

I am currently having a Db in Postgres with a timestamp column setup as below:

```
    ts timestamp with time zone not null default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
```

this is saving the ts :

```
2017-08-22 10:34:21.547703+00
```

This the utc time.

```
2017-08-22T10:34:21.547703+00:00 format ISO8601
```

I found this 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:MS"Z"' but I still do not want the 'Z'

I am not finding the way to add the `T`between date and time and also why the TZ show as +00 instead of +00:00 in my current format, I do not want the space and also the TZ should also reflect the minutes. Right now it's only hour

Comment: why not adding minutes to TZ manually? like `select to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:MSOF":00"');`

Comment: IMO (in most cases) you should to care about textual timestamp representation at the client (python) side.